# How to pass JSON array correctly into JQPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqplot

I'm having a few issues getting a JSON array to be processed correctly by a JQPlot graph for some reason. I suspect that the array is being interpreted as a single value and not as a sequence of values.

I have a function that makes an ajax call to a php script. The php script computes the graphing data and echo's it back to the user like so:

```
$retdata = array(); 
$retdata['date'] = array($ann_dates);
$retdata['close'] = array($closeperdiff);
$retdata['high'] = array($highperdiff);
$retdata['low'] = array($lowperdiff);
echo json_encode($retdata);
```

Here is the ajax call on the client side:

```
function getgraph(symbol)
{
  var datastring = "symbol=" + symbol;
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "quickview.php",
            data: datastring,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function( data ) {
                drawgraph(data);

            },
            error: function(){
                  alert('Error somewhere');
            }
        });
}
```

Now, finally my JQPLot function 'drawgraph' is called and the data is passed. I'm using JSON.parse to separate the data, I just can't work this into JQPlot correctly. When I run this it essentially just display the first number of the first bar. I suspect the dates are a single string of one long value.

I have tried different variations of " [  ] " in the jqplot function but to no avail. I'm a little stumped!

```
function drawgraph(garray)
{
          var obj = JSON.parse(garray);

          //alert(obj["high"]) displays: 1,3,2,1,0,1
          //alert(obj["date"]) displays:  2015-05-29,2015-05-12,2015-04-30,2015-03-30,2015-02-27,2015-02-26 


          s1 = obj["high"];
          s2 = obj["low"];
          s3 = obj["close"];
          ticks = obj["date"];

          plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', s1, s2, s3, {
                        title:'Bar Chart with Custom Colors',
                // Provide a custom seriesColors array to override the default colors.
                seriesColors:['#D1FFC2', '#ffCCCC', '#aeaeae'],
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                pointLabels: { show: true }
            },
            legend: {
        // This renderer is needed for advance legends.
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
        show: true, 
        location: 's', 
        placement: 'outside',
        // Breaks the ledgend into horizontal.
        rendererOptions: {
          numberRows: '1',
          numberColumns: '3',
                barWidth: 25,
                barPadding:-10,
                barMargin: -10
        },
        seriesToggle: true
      },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: [ticks]
                }
            }
        });

        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                $('#info2').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
            }
        );

        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight', 
            function (ev) {
                $('#info2').html('Nothing');
            }
        );

}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle, just for starters change `dataType: "html",` to `dataType: "json"`, so you do not need to parse explicitely.

Comment: If cant fiddle then provide, jqPlot's expected input format and the response you are getting in AJAX